# Sumifs several sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum up all numbers using three criteria:

```
Criterion 1: Person A, B or C
Criterion 2: Head
Criterion 3: FTE
```

Here is my Uerbesicht or overview sheet, where I would like to have my code to inset sumif formula with the above three criteria:

[image]

This is the sheet 1, as an example, which I am counting.

[image]

This is my code

```
Dim m As String
m = "a;b;c"

Dim uebersicht As Worksheet
    Set uebersicht = ActiveSheet
    Dim i As Integer

  For m = "a" To "c"
    For i = 1 To 8
        For j = 4 To 6 'column number
            For k = 2 To 17 'row number
        uebersicht.Cells(j, k).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets(i).Range("B2:B4"), Sheets(i).Range("A2:A4"), m)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
  Next m
```

My code is not working. I appreciate your help.

Comment: `For m = "a" To "c"` - you can't loop like that... use `Array` to hold each individual element, or `Split` to generate an array based on the concatenated string.

Comment: This can be done with a formula put this in B3:  `=SUMIFS(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!B:C"),0,MATCH(B$2,INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!B1:C1"),0)),INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!A:A"),$A3)` copy over and down